# Firebase Cloud Landmark Detector for Flutter Missing

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-mlkit

The ML Vision Plugin for Flutter currently doesn't contain a cloudLandmarkDetector to use with Firebase Landmark Recognition. 
Will that be added to the plugin in the future or are there any alternatives like direct HTTP calls to run the cloud detection / open Tensorflow model?

Comment: Have you got any answer regarding this? I suppose, that it will be added on the long run. Since the plugin information states, that some functionalities are currently missing.

Comment: No answer, I guess we won't be seeing that anytime soon